# Switching writing from file to stdout using "sink()" in R

Tags: r, file, stdout, keyboardinterrupt, sink

I implemented the following procedure that aims to write some files and print a message in the end of each file when the writing is done:

```
# Print one file per piaf
output_dir_piafs <- "OUTPUT_dataset_piafs"
unlink(output_dir_piafs, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
dir.create(output_dir_piafs)
for (i in 1:length(lst_sorted)) {
    sink()      # Generates warnings...
    filename <- paste(output_dir_piafs, "/piaf_", i, ".txt", sep="")
    sink(file = filename, append = TRUE)
    sink(type = "message")
    cat("  ", colnames(file1), "\n")

    for (j in 1:length(lst_sorted[[i]])) {
        cat(j, " ")
        lapply( lst_sorted[[i]][[j]], 
                function(x) { 
                    cat(as.character(x), " ")
                }
        )
        cat("\n")
    }

    ## back to the console
    sink()
    cat(paste(filename, "done !\n"))
    #flush(stdout())        # Tested, no particular effect
}
```

My problem is that, if I do not add a `sink()` at the very beginning of the loop, the final writing on the standard output (`cat(paste(filename, "done !\n"))`) has no effect. On the other hand, adding this early `sink()` generates warnings that I would like to avoid:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In sink() : no sink to remove
2: In sink() : no sink to remove
3: In sink() : no sink to remove
```

Does anyone has an idea on how sink() behaves, and/or how to get rid of those warnings?

***Note:** I also tried `try(sink(), silent=TRUE)`, but the `silent` option prevents only from errors...*

Comment: Just a silly thought. Have you tried your code from a fresh R session? Perhaps you have some connections open, try `sink.number("message")`.

Comment: Good thinking! `sink.number("message")` doesn't return anything, but from a fresh new session, the standard output gets written fine. It is only when I stop the process (`Ctrl-C`), then re-run it, that the standard output fails. So, I think you're right. My bad: interrupting the process might have some bad consequences on the `stdout` connection. Moreover, if I type `sink()` right before re-running the process, it still doesn't work...

Comment: I made some other tests. If I let the process terminate properly, then re-run it, everything works well. This is definitely the `Ctrl-C` interruption which generates the issue. Any suggestion about how to make the things right, after having interrupted that way?

Comment: Been there, done that, bought the t-shirt, didn't like it. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `sink`, have a look at `?cat`, which can directly write to a file.

The following code should work:

```
output_dir_piafs <- "OUTPUT_dataset_piafs"
unlink(output_dir_piafs, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
dir.create(output_dir_piafs)
lst_sorted <- c(1,2,3)
file1 <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3)
for (i in 1:length(lst_sorted)) {
  filename <- paste(output_dir_piafs, "/piaf_", i, ".txt", sep="")
  cat("  ", colnames(file1), "\n", file=filename, append=T)
  for (j in 1:length(lst_sorted[[i]])) {
    cat(j, " ", file=filename, append=T)
    lapply( lst_sorted[[i]][[j]], 
           function(x) { 
             cat(as.character(x), " ", file=filename, append=T)
           }
           )
    cat("\n", file=filename, append=T)
  }
  cat(paste(filename, "done !\n"))
}
```

Please note that I set the variables `lst_sorted` and `file1` in order to make the code reproducible.

Does the `cat` solution work for you?

Comment: Yep, it works, but it also takes twice the time `sink` takes to write the data into the files. Which is quite annoying... I suppose doing this results in opening/closing the file connection at each `cat`.

Comment: concerning the speed, just create f <- file(filename, 'w') before your loop, then call cat() with file=f

Comment: @KarlForner Ok, thanks! That could make the `cat` user1981275's solution viable. We'll see if with the `Ctrl-C` interruption, we still need to close the file in a `tryCatch`...

Comment: @user1981275 Thanks for your help! Just a remark: the `cat("\n")`, should be written in the file as well: `cat("\n", file=filename, append=T)`.

Answer (score 3):

I finally fixed the issue by adding a `sink(type="output")` when catching the interruption - `Ctrl-C` - (this makes the things right for later usage of the standard output - which would remain locked/diversion otherwise):

```
tryCatch({

    # Print one file per piaf
    output_dir_piafs <- "OUTPUT_dataset_piafs"
    unlink(output_dir_piafs, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
    dir.create(output_dir_piafs)
    for (i in 1:length(lst_sorted)) {
        filename <- paste(output_dir_piafs, "/piaf_", i, ".txt", sep="")
        sink(file = filename, append = TRUE)
        sink(type = "message")
        cat("  ", colnames(file1), "\n")

        for (j in 1:length(lst_sorted[[i]])) {
            cat(j, " ")
            lapply( lst_sorted[[i]][[j]], 
                    function(x) { 
                        cat(as.character(x), " ")
                    }
            )
            cat("\n")
        }

        ## back to the console
        sink(type="output")
        cat(paste(filename, "done !\n"))
    }

}, interrupt = function(ex) {

    ##cat("An interrupt was detected.\n")
    sink(type="output")            # Restore the standard output !
    ##print(ex)

}) # tryCatch()
```

The other way to do (based on the help of [user1981275](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981275/user1981275) and [Karl Forner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448145/karl-forner)), would have been:

```
tryCatch({

    # Print one file per piaf
    output_dir_piafs <- "OUTPUT_dataset_piafs_2"
    unlink(output_dir_piafs, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
    dir.create(output_dir_piafs)
    for (i in 1:length(lst_sorted)) {
        filename <- paste(output_dir_piafs, "/piaf_", i, ".txt", sep="")
        f <- file(filename, 'w')
        cat("  ", colnames(file1), "\n", file=f)

        for (j in 1:length(lst_sorted[[i]])) {
            cat(j, " ", file=f)
            lapply( lst_sorted[[i]][[j]], 
                    function(x) { 
                        cat(as.character(x), " ", file=f)
                    }
            )
            cat("\n", file=f)
        }

        flush(f)
        close(f)
        ## back to the console
        cat(paste(filename, "done !\n"))
    }

}, interrupt = function(ex) {

    closeAllConnections()

}) # tryCatch()
```

This solution has the great advantage to not make a diversion of the standard output, meaning that, even without catching the interruption, the standard output remains active.

*Note that **Keyboard Interruption** handling is still necessary to avoid warnings like:*

```
> warnings()
Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (OUTPUT_dataset_piafs_2/piaf_16.txt)
```

Accordingly to `?closeAllConnections`:

> ‘closeAllConnections’ closes (and destroys) all user connections,
>   restoring all ‘sink’ diversions as it does so.

***Last Note:*** No real speed difference regarding file writing between those two methods.